# Refreshing random in an if case

Tags: android

I generate two random int numbers (a and b). If (a%b)==0 that I want to go on, else I want to change the randoms by refreshing. I give an example code:

```
int a = //random;
int b = //random;
if ((a%b)==0) {
   // do something
} else {
   // I want to change a and b and do that if case again.
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?  `void m(){ // init a & b; if (a%b!=0) m(); // do something`

Comment: you can use while loop, see my answer

Comment: Thank you @Elior . Your and Mike Young's answers are the same. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a= // random
int b= // random
while ((a%b)!=0) 
 { a = // random;
   b = // random;
 }
// a and b are random and out of the loop which means (a%b)==0
// do something with a and b
```

Comment: wow, you wrote this answer after me.. and still you get the points

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = //random;
int b = //random;
while((a%b)!=0) {
   a = // random
   b = // random
 }
 // do something
```

so in that way, when a%b is not equal to 0, it will generate new random for a and b
when the condition of the while loop is false it will stop to generate this and then you can resume your code

Comment: Oh, sorry. I couldn't see it first. :)